# How to generate html layout using xml coord points

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml that looks like this:

```
...

<ImageRegion id="r0">
    <Coords points="0,0 0,523 1365,523 1365,892 2048,892 2048,377 92,377 2048,377 2048,0"/>
</ImageRegion>

<TextRegion id="r2" type="caption">
    <Coords points="1021,81 1021,182 40,182 40,81"/>
    <TextEquiv conf="0.63228">
        <Unicode>Lorem Ipsum</Unicode>
    </TextEquiv>
</TextRegion>
...
```

the coord points give the x,y axis for all points of the region (which can be any kind of polygon, usually rectangular). There are multiple img and text regions.

I want to write xslt (or anything) to get the same layout in html as it is in xml, but I'm cant figure it out.

Edit1: 
I'm generating the xml using an png-img. I basically want to convert the img to html. I  have cmpny tools that generate OCR and other things. I need to generate a layout which specifies where text/imgs will go.

[image: the marked regions can be seen clearly, bg removed.]

As seen in the img, the area marked are represented in the XML file. I want to create the same layout in a HTML page.

Comment: can you post the html output based on your input?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I wrote a python script to read the xml and generate html.

The html looks like this:

```
<svg>
<g id="r1" class="img">
    <polygon points="31,1757 30,3131 2017,3131 2018,1757"
                style="fill:rgb(121,0,121);stroke-width:3; stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-opacity:0.5;opacity:0.5">
    </polygon>
</g>

<g id="r2" class="text">
    <text x="530.5" y="131.5" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem Ipsum
    </text>
    <polygon points="1021,81 1021,182 40,182 40,81"
                style="fill:rgb(50,50,121);stroke-width:3; stroke:rgb(0,0,0); stroke-opacity:0.5;opacity:0.5">
    </polygon>
</g>
</svg>
```